# Iterate over list by index

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing

For an experiment I want to create multiple rectangles, one of which is a target rectangle. 
Therefore I have created a list with x, y coordinates

```
xy_list = xy_circle(8, 200)
random.shuffle(xy_list)
```

And the code for the rarget rectangle, with x, y coordinates xy_list[0]

```
target_rectangle = visual.Rect(win=mywin4, width=45, height=90, pos(xy_list[0]), lineColor='white', fillColor='blue', ori=orientations_list[1])
target_rectangle.draw()
```

And to save me some time and space I want to create a for loop for the distractor rectangles, using the indexes 1-7 of the xy_list. But I'm new to Python so I am not sure how to do this. Could anyone maybe give me a hint? It would be greatly appreciated.

```
for x, y in xy_list: 
    distractor_rectangle = visual.Rect(win=mywin4, width=45, height=90, pos=(x, y), fillColor='white')
    distractor_rectangle.draw()
```

Comment: `for x, y in xy_list[1:8]:`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()` to iterate through the indexes and them access them by `xy_list[index]` :

```
for i in range(1,8):
    distractor_rectangle = visual.Rect(win=mywin4, width=45, height=90, pos=xy_list[i], fillColor='white')
    distractor_rectangle.draw()
```